# Send a message between application users

Tags: facebook, messaging

I want to write a facebook app in which I'll show a list of the people who gave permission to use the app.
Each user would be able to pick another user from the list and send them a message from the app.
Is there any facebook api call I can use? Or I have to develop a stand alone messaging system?